# Sci-fi movie seen in early 2000s about an alien-like plant kept in a government vault

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was a sci-fi movie I watched with my mother 20 years ago.

I can't remember the cast, but the one scene I recall was the son (in his 30s) saying to not open Vault 7 in sector 13 of a government facility. It had something to do with an alien-like plant whose roots would destroy or consume the planet and possibly its people if the vault were opened.

I remember them asking him how he was so sure about this and it was because his parent had carved them into his hands and told him enough times for it to stick from a young age. I also recall the vault not being on the map of the "facility;" it was stumbled upon during reconstruction or building.

Does anyone have any ideas? My mother believes it to be an '80s to early '90s sci-fi.

Comment: Do you remember if it specifically referred to "vault" and "sector" and if it was those specific numbers? And what do you mean by "carved them into his hands"? Did they cut symbols or instructions into the skin?

Comment: It could almost be an episode of [Warehouse 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warehouse_13).

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: By the way, thank you for accepting the answer. Usually I post a helpful comment to let people know how, but you figured it out on your own. Sincere congratulations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is ***[Living Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_Hell_(film))*** AKA *Organizm* (2008).

> *Living Hell* (aka *Organizm* - DVD title) is a 2008 horror television film written and directed by Richard Jefferies, which stars Johnathon Schaech and Erica Leerhsen. It premiered on Sci Fi Channel on February 23, and was released on DVD on June 10, 2008.

The protagonist, Frank Sears, is a high school biology teacher. When he was still a foetus in his mother's womb, she was a soldier working at Fort Lambert, a US Army base in New Mexico, which is where she met his father, a Russian scientist developing a biological weapon there.

Frank's father inadvertently caused the weapon he was trying to create -- an infectious plant-like organism -- to manifest within his own body. To prevent the organism from spreading, his body was sealed in a vat behind a wall in Sublevel 3, Vault 12 of the base, and all official records of the experiment were destroyed. When Frank was nine years old, his mother hysterically etched the letters and numbers "S3" and "V12" into the palms of his hands with a pencil, warning him that something bad was locked away there, which must never be disturbed.

> [image: Image of Frank's palms, scarred with the letters and numbers "S3" and "V12," from "Living Hell" (2008).]
>
> <sub>*Living Hell* (2008)</sub>

33 years later, Frank learned that Fort Lambert was being torn down, and drove there to warn the Army about whatever was locked away in Sublevel 3, Vault 12. However, his doing so leads to the discovery of his father's body, causing the plant-like organism to rapidly spread out of the base and into surrounding towns. It's growth is stimulated by light, which is why it wasn't growing when it was sealed away in darkness. It's also immune to conventional, chemical, and even nuclear weapons, so the Army's attempts to halt its growth are unsuccessful.

It's later discovered that Frank's blood triggers an autoimmune reaction within the organism, since his DNA is similar to its own, and he's able to kill the entire thing by plunging his bloody hands into the organism's nucleus, which is located within his father's corpse in Fort Lambert.

> [image: Image of Frank plunging his bloody hands into the organism's nucleus within his father's corpse, from "Living Hell" (2008).]
>
> <sub>*Living Hell* (2008)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Organism is the name of the movie. I looked for days before finally finding the name

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Which movie named [*Organism*](https://www.imdb.com/find/?q=organism&ref_=nv_sr_sm)?  How does it match the question?  I don't see any that fit the given information.  Please provide all the required details for the asker to recognize the movie as the one they are asking about.  Please also note that this question already has an accepted answer, so you need to make a really good case that this is a _better_ fit.

Comment: _Organizm_ is the alternate title of _Living Hell_, the film named in the [previous answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/271622/122024). The alternate title is acknowledged near the top of that answer.