Movie has a small body a green organic tissue (if I remember correctly) in an underground base that eventually grows and escapes?
There was a movie I watched when I was younger with my dad which I'd guess came out ~80-90s, which had an underground base/facility where multiple weird creatures were kept. One was notable for being a skull-like head with legs and a bottom at the back, while the other was a type of green organic tissue which grew quickly and took over the base to then escape.

In roughly which year did you actually watch this?

The Thing perhaps?  It took over bodies and turned into some of the creatures you described.  Kurt Russel 1982.

Almost certainly The Thing

The Thing is vaguely similar, but it's hardly a spot-on match.

Does the plotline involve a protagonist whose scientist father carved instructions on their arm when they were a child?

Ah, Living Hell (aka Organizm) came out in 2008 as per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/271615/sci-fi-movie-seen-in-early-2000s-about-an-alien-like-plant-kept-in-a-government so it wouldn't be that one.

@FuzzyBoots - Living Hell was my first thought when I read the title, but it doesn't have multiple weird creatures or the skull creature with legs, just the plant-like organism. The 2008 release date doesn't necessarily disqualify it, though, since the OP didn't say when they watched the film, only when they think it was made. People asking about low budget films here often think they're older than they turn out to be.

Unfortunately the '80s was full of low budget secret laboratory. Weird creature movies. Was the military involved? Was it on Earth?

@ArlettaS The military was involved and it did take place on earth. I think the tissue escaped and they watched from a distance on a relatively flat plain, almost like a desert.
